# unable to mount external drive from cron (using udisksctl)

Tags: command-line, mount, cron, policykit, udisks

### GOAL

I'd like to mount an external drive using  `cron` for automatic backups, preferably with `udisksctl`.

### PROBLEM

`udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdXY` works fine from the command line or shell script, but when I run it from cron (using my own cron table), it fails with the message

```
Error creating textual authentication agent: Error opening current controlling terminal for the process (`/dev/tty'): No such device or address (polkit-error-quark, 0)
Error mounting /dev/sdXY: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.NotAuthorizedCanObtain: Not authorized to perform operation
```

### WHAT I'VE TRIED

In `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.UDisks2.policy`, I edited the action `org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount`, changing the default value of `allow_inactive` from `auth_admin` to `yes`, so it matches the value of `allow_active`, so that section now looks like this:

```
    <defaults>
      <allow_any>auth_admin</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>yes</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
    </defaults>
```

I tried both `sudo systemctl restart polkit.service` and rebooting my machine, but I still get the same message and can't run `udisksctl mount` from `cron`.

#### System info

```
$ uname -a
Linux <hostname> 5.15.0-97-generic #107-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 7 13:26:48 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
```

Comment: I've posted my answer but not with `cron` instead with *udev* and *systemd* approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Ubuntu 23.10 and later

Create and edit a `.rules` file under `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/` like:

```
sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/10-udisks.rules
```

... and to allow a certain user, copy/paste the following in it, changing `user` to your username:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount" &&
        subject.user == "user") {
        return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
});
```

... or, this instead, to allow any user:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount") {
        return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
});
```

##### Ubuntu 23.04 and earlier

Create and edit a `.pkla` file under `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/` like:

```
sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/10-udisks.pkla
```

... and to allow a certain user, copy/paste the following in it, changing `user` to your username:

```
[Allow Mounting From User Cron]
Identity=unix-user:user
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount
ResultAny=yes
```

... or, this instead, to allow any user:

```
[Allow Mounting From User Cron]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount
ResultAny=yes
```

Comment: I tried this followed by a `... restart polkit.service`, but it still fails with the same message.  I'm not sure how this rule would alter behavior under `cron`.  I can already mount/umount from the command line, and it doesn't change that.

Comment: Ok, reading the [polkit man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html), I understand why this solution **should** work, but it does not (for me).

Comment: @petermao I believe this solution requires polkit > 1.06, which doesn't appear in the Ubuntu world until 23.10 (Mantic) - see for example [PolicyKit rules never come into effect](https://askubuntu.com/a/704062/178692) and [What's going on with PolicyKit?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1287935/178692)

Comment: @steeldriver Ah ... Tested on 23.10 so missed that ... Now added for 23.04 and earlier ... Thanks a ton :-)

Comment: @petermao I edited the answer and added a way for older versions of `polkitd` ... Please accept my apology for the inconvenience.

Comment: @raffa thank you so much for taking the time to write up this up. I've adopted your solution, whcih is much more aligned with the intent of polkit.

Comment: I'd like to add that this solution works without needing to run `sudo systemctl restart polkit.service`.  After adding the `pkla` file as described above, it just works!

Answer (score 0):

### Solution (with security implications?)

I changed the `allow_any` default from `auth_admin` to `yes`, followed by `... restart polkit.service`.  Now the drive mounts from `cron`.  The entry in the `...Udisks2.policy` file now looks like this:

```
    <defaults>
      <allow_any>yes</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>auth_admin</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
    </defaults>
```

**Q: Are there any negative security implications with this setting?**

Comment: I see no security harm with that more than a dedicated rule file AFAIK ... But the default policy files might be overwritten/altered on system/package updates so, not guaranteed to hold  your modification then.