How to give user permission to use udisksctl? [Ubuntu LTS 22.04]
I don't have the rep yet to be able to comment on the existing post, so I'm forced to make a new post. Apologies.
GOAL: To be able to mount USB drives on boot without loading the GUI to be used for automated backups, etc.
I cannot use udisksctl mount -b /dev/sda1 --no-user-interaction with my current user because I get the error:
Error mounting /dev/sda1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.NotAuthorizedCanObtain: Not authorized to perform operation
Searching this forum, I found this answer to the same question:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1504550/1769048
But this does not work for me on 22.04. After I create the 10-udisks.pkla file, even after a reboot, I get the same error. Is there something else I need to do to make this work?
Contents of my pkla file:
[Allow Mounting From User Cron]
Identity=unix-user:<redacted>
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount
ResultAny=yes

UPDATE: I've gone back to just using the drive's UUID in an fstab mount which is working fine. But for the sake of learning, I would love to know how to make this work using udisksctl.

What does your 10-udisks.pkla file contain, exactly?

Located at: /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/10-udisks.pkla >
[Allow Mounting From User Cron]
Identity=unix-user:<redacted>
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount
ResultAny=yes

I added it to my original post since formatting in here was not wonderful.
